# Android ListView rows are repeating if i don't re-query the needed info from the database

Tags: android, android-listview, listadapter, listviewitem, android-viewholder

It's my first time working with listviews so excuse me in advance for any beginner errors.

My code for the custom getView is as follows:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder mHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        /*Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "nullConvertView", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();*/
        mHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);


        mHolder.PetName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.PetName);

        mHolder.PetImage = (RoundedImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.PetImage);



        updateItem(mHolder, this.getItem(position));

        convertView.setTag(mHolder);
    } else {
        mHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

The function updateItem connects to a dropbox datastore and retrieves the informations such as datastore title and image (each row in the listview is a dropbox datastore) and then sets them through mHolder.PetName.setText(queriedresultstring) ecc

If i keep the code this way i get repeated views when scrolling, while if i move the updateItem function outside of the if/else condition everything works fine, but everytime i scroll the listview it queries again the database for each row that reappears on screen.

Is there any way to keep the informations stored on the view without having to query the database each time the view returns on screen?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than query the database in your `updateItem()` method, use a `Loader` to query the data and build a local data store which is used to back your adapter (such as an `ArrayList`.)  Alternatively, you could use a `Loader` which queries the backend the caches the data in a local database so your `Loader` would have to have the logic to use the local database rather than submitting a new query (if possible.)  It's up to you to decide how to manage that.

BTW, the reason you need to have your current `updateItem()` outside of the `if/else` condition check is because otherwise the recycled views don't get updated with the correct data binding.

Comment: could you make some example code with Loader and/or ArrayList? you can hypotize that there's a function String retrievetext(position) that returns the text that i have to display in the view at int position.

Comment: How about an article on using [Loaders](http://po.st/xHoVMf)? This sample shows pulling data form a `ContentProvider`, but you could apply the same principle with an http request.  You'd need to create your own `Loader` based on `AsyncTaskLoader` to do it; or, you could bypass using a `Loader` and (carefully) use your own `AsyncTask` or thread to pull the data from the back end. This article on basic sensor usage has sample code which uses a simple adapter with the list of all sensors to give you a better idea of the adapter mechanics: http://po.st/BKmQgo

Comment: the data from the datastore is retrieved quite fast but the scrolling lags. I've got a listener which is triggered whenever the online datastore changes so i think that i only need to store the data on an arraylist, though i have no idea on the way to implement it

Comment: If scrolling is lagging then the data is likely not being retrieved all that quickly.  The goal for rendering is 60fps, which means you have about 16ms to render a frame.  I'd suggest using a `Loader` or event a background thread to pull your data from the datastore, then store it in an `ArrayList` which you then pass to your `Adapter`.

Comment: I partially solved the issue by using an hashmap that uses datastore id as key. But now i'm facing another issue as updateItem has to know when to recreate the hashmap. Inside the listener that is triggered when online datastore i've put a boolean that sets itself to true, then calls the function that populates the adapter and then goes false. for some reason when the function is called the boolean goes again to false, do you have any idea on what could be the issue?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow what you are facing.  Rather than carry this on in the comments, it would be better to mark this one has having an answer then post a new issue/question so it's clear.